# finding the temperature after a period of time

Tags: calculus

I have a homework problem that I am really struggling with. I will put the problem below and then discuss what I have tried to do.

A science geek brews tea at $195$ °F, and observes that the temperature $T(t)$ of the tea after $t$ minutes is changing at the rate of $T′(t)=−4.5e^{−0.07t}$ °F/min. What is the average temperature of the tea during the first $5$ minutes after being brewed? Round your answer to the nearest hundredth of a degree.

I tried to integrate from $0$ to $5$ minutes but I couldn't get the right answer does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You have to integrate the equation from $0$ to $5$. Next you have to divide your result with $5$. Then you have the average temperature.

Comment: I got 52.4472 and dividing it by 5 i got 10.48944 but i dont think thats possibly the answer can anyone help?

Comment: The equation starts at $195 °F$. So I think the equation is: $195 - 4.5e^{-0.07t}$. After integrating and dividing by 5, I get $173.08 °F$

Comment: even trying that its saying its not right

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** :
 The average value of a function $f(x)$ on the intervall $[a,b]$ is given by :
 $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

Here $f=T$, so you need to integrate to get $T(t)$ then to obtain the average value.

---

1. Obtain an expression for $T$.
   $T(0)=195$, so $T(t)=\int_0^tT'(s)ds+T(0)=\int_0^t−4.5e^{−0.07s}ds+195=−4.5\int_0^te^{−0.07s}ds+195=\frac{4,5}{0.07}[e^{-0.07s}]_0^t+195=\frac{4,5}{0.07}(e^{-0.07t}-1)+195$
2. Use the formula for the average value of the function :
   $$\frac{1}{5-0}\int_0^5T(x)dx=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^5\frac{4,5}{0.07}(e^{-0.07t}-1)+195dt=10\int_0^5e^{-0.07t}dt-50+195=-\frac{10}{0.07}(
   e^{-0.35}-1)+145\approx187.187$$

Comment: what answer did you get? I got the same answer as the guy above and its wrong

Comment: added the answer

Comment: @google Did it answer your question ?

Comment: its still saying that its wrong. I dont know what it could be

Comment: @google I did a mistake in last line can you check the new result ?